How do I cut a narrow slice of a 20mm porcelain coping tile (L shape profile) without chipping it?
Here is the tile picture from the manufacturer. Notice that that corner seems to be glued; it was not fabricated that way. The slice that I need will have to be like 2" wide. I am afraid of chipping that corner piece.


Not sure exactly what you are asking.   Are you saying that you are purchasing  a tile just as shown in the picture and have a need to cut a 2 inch piece from it?

What tools do you have available? You should be able to cut it with a wet diamond wheel as you'd cut any tile.

With a good saw, you can make a couple of practice cuts before cutting the full 2 inches.

I have angle grinder with continuous diamond blade, hand held wet saw and a ridgid table wet saw

If needing a perfectly straight line, the table saw will be the best.  The others need a good eye and a steady hand.  A guide should be be used.

My concern is to avoid chipping that corner

Best thing to avoid chipping is the purchase of a new good quality blade and install on your saw before cutting the tile.

I asm considering using a dremel to cut enough to be able to continue with something else after that

This was cut using a Ryobi wet hand tile saw. Get rid of the stock blade, that is garbage. Get a blade that is designed for both wet and dry cuts.
Make the cut along the long side of the cut.
Two passes to completely cut the 20mm horizontal side of the L
That is the wet cut.
Then switch off the water supply and using the existing top cut as a guide position bottom plate of the saw to form a 45 degree angle with the vertical of the L. Execute a plunge cut from that angle
The water must be cut because it is going to be mostly useless it is going to drip on you not on the blade especially toward the end of the cut when the saw will be in the vertical position. You start at 45 degrees and while you do the plunge cut you are closing that agle. 
